# Attribute Tables with drop down menus from lookup tables with joins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, attribute-joins, domains

I am attempting to create drop down lists when editing attributes in Arcgis Desktop in order to eliminate human errors. Through using domains I managed to carry this out successfully and the drop down lists work well.
However I have an application that caters for lookup tables and not domains, and in order to avoid having to modify both the lookup table and the domain I want to create drop down lists for attributes on Desktop using lookup tables with joins.
Is there a way of doing this as I can't seem to carry this out successfully?

Comment: You can use subtypes to define different feature templates so when user will create new features they will need to choose a template that can have multiple pre-defined attributes. However, the drop-down list of legal values is available only through domains that you assign to fields. It's possible to build own logic for this using ArcObjects, but I doubt that this is an option for you.

Comment: So there is no way of creating the drop down list for attribute values by linking a data table with an attribute within the layer table via joins? I will try out using feature templates however this would still mean if I have to do updates to the data table I would also have to update the feature template each time which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Correct. You have to use domains. You shouldn't be afraid of updating your domains. You can keep your codes/values in a geodatabase table and then use GP tools to update your domains either manually or via Python scripting, it's fairly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to carry this out successfully with the following process:

- A data table was created within arcmap with an id field and a data field, while a foreign key was created in the layer attributes of the layer I wanted to attach the data table to.
- This data table then had to be added to the map using the add data tool and only afterwards would the map and the layer be published together as a service.
  -In this way the relationship would actually be published as part of the service.
  -I then used this code to check the service for any relationships:

  ```
  //related tables
  var relatedQuery = new RelationshipQuery();
  relatedQuery.outFields = [dataTableDataField];
  relatedQuery.relationshipId = relationsId;
  relatedQuery.objectIds = [IDOfObjectBeingEdited];
  relatedTableResult = [];
  displayText = "";
  graphic._graphicsLayer.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, function (relatedRecords) {

  relatedTableResult = relatedRecords[graphicObjectId];
  //Code to map the related data to the editable attribute window and populate dropdown list with the retrieved data can then be placed here
  ```

  }

This allowed for dropdown lists based on the created relationships when editing the attributes of a feature on a particular layer